# Original paper about the all or none law for neurons

Tags: neuroscience, history, action-potential

I am looking for the original paper about the all or none law for neural activity.

I know that there is a very old article about the all or none law for mammalian heart muscle fibers, but I'm specifically interested in when this idea was first stated about neural activity.

In [**A logical calculus of the ideas immanent in nervous activity**](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/bf02478259#page-1) from 1943 this law is already mentioned like an established hypothesis, so it is probably quite old.

Comment: I would guess on the Hodgkin-Huxley paper.

Comment: Hodgkin-Huxley seems to be too new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably goes back to Lucas (1909), Adrian (1912), and Bernstein (1912). But the idea might have started from Helmholtz (1850).

- Lucas, K (1909). The ``all or none'' contraction of the amphibian skeletal muscle fibre. Journal of Physiology; 38: 113--133.
- Adrian, ED (1912). On the conduction of subnormal disturbances in normal nerve. Journal of Physiology; 45: 389--412
- Bernstein, J (1912). Electrobiologie. Braunschweig: Vieweg.

See also: [Galvani's Spark: The Story of the Nerve Impulse](http://amzn.to/1RniODL) and [The great Era of English Electrophysiology:
from Francis Gotch to Hodgkin and Huxley](http://www.architalbiol.org/aib/article/viewFile/14977/pdf)